# -vg-root does not exist

Tags: boot, initramfs

I have seen several similar questions to mine but none seen to address the specific issue.  I have been getting the *-vg-root does not exist error on a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine after a crash.  The root device does appear under /dev/mapper and lvm vgdisplay lists it, however it is missing from blkid.  I am not really sure what to do from here?  How do I restore the blkid entry?  In the image below the link to dm-0 for root was missing - I created it manually.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide the output of `ls -l /dev/mapper/` and `lvdisplay`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your volume group name is **elysium-oc-vg** but partitions **root** & **swap_1** are considered to be a part of **elysium--oc--vg** (additional `-` in the name).

So try the following `cd /dev/mapper/`, `unlink elysium--oc--vg-root`, `ln -s ../dm-0 elysium-oc-vg-root` and reboot the server. If everything is fine, do the same for **swap** partition.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it was unsuccessful.  Comparing to another VM we have I think the way I had created the link was correct.